# I am taking **GPS location** through **runtime permission** but it does not set the **location ON** in the emulator on android?

Tags: java, android

I am taking **GPS location** through  **runtime permission** but it does not set the **location ON** in the emulator on android?

```
private void requestRuntimePermission() {
    android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions ( this, new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET
    }, per_code );

}


public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult ( requestCode,permissions,grantResults );

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission ( this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION )==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    Toast.makeText ( MainActivity.this, "Permission given ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show ();

                    textview.setText ( "Location Services Is Enabled" );
                    download ();
                    location ();
                    handle ();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: because,  emulator doesn't support GPS you have to set the latlng manually

Comment: how i can do it manually ... i have declared permission in manifest file

Comment: goto your emulator setting-> location change latlng and save emulator doesn't support GPS you have to run it on real time device

Comment: There are some applications that can simulate GPS changes and i think it worked on the emuletor too. Search for something like mock location! So you can test and debug your logic on a simulated device :)

Comment: thanks for replying ... Roberto Manfreda  ... code is running fine but emulator does not set the location ON

Comment: HussainAbbas ... through that way i have changed the  latitude and longitude many time but nothing happens